# How to add two variables values using Kusto query?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm new to Kusto query. I've to add two variable values using Kusto query. How to do that.

```
let c1 = tablename | count;
let c2 = tablename1 | count;
print c1+c2
```

the above query is not working

Comment: When you get an error message you are expected to share it as part of your post. In the future, please avoid vague descriptions such as "not working".

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz: Thank you.. Sure. query working fine after using toscalar() function

Comment: Please close the loop by accepting the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your query fails with the following error message:

> 'project' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'c1'

This happens since c1 (as well as c2) is a tabular expression and not a scalar.

[toscalar()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction) can be used to do the required conversion.

```
let tablename = StormEvents;
let tablename1 = ConferenceSessions;
let c1 = toscalar(tablename | count);
let c2 = toscalar(tablename1 | count);
print c1+c2
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| 59116 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoSUzKSc1LzE1VsFUILskvynUtS80rKbbmykGWNATKOufnpaUWpeYlpwanFhdn5udBFSWDJEvyi5MTcxKLNBDm1Sgk55fmlWhCVRlhVWWIpKygKDMPZJx2shEAjgB42poAAAA=)